# What are possible causes for Spring @ComponentScan being unable to auto create a class anotated by @Repository

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-orm

I came across a [tutorial](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-eight-adding-functionality-to-a-repository/) which seemed to be fitting my usecase and tried implementing it. I failed but wasn't sure why. So I tried to find another example with similar code and looked at the book **"Spring in Action, Fourth Edition by Craig Walls"**

The books describes at page 300 the same basic approach. Define a JdbcTemplate Bean first.

```
@Bean
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

Then a Repository implementing an Interface

```
@Repository
public class CustomRepositoryImpl implements CustomRepository {

private final NamedParameterJdbcOperations jdbcOperations;

private static final String TEST_STRING = "";

@Autowired
public CustomRepositoryImpl(NamedParameterJdbcOperations jdbcOperations) {
    this.jdbcOperations = jdbcOperations;
}
```

So I did like the example in the book suggests, wrote a test but got the error message

> Error creating bean with name 'de.myproject.config.SpringJPAPerformanceConfigTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'abc'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'de.myproject.CustomRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

To my understanding as book and tutorial describe, the Repository should be recognized as a Bean definition by the component scan.

To test this I created an context and asked for all registered Beans.

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext 
context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
context.getBeanDefinitionNames()
```

As assumed my Repository wasn't among them. So I increased, for test purposes only, scope of the search in my project, and set it to the base package. Every other Bean was shown, except the Repository.

As an alternative to component scanning and autowiring, the books describes the possibility to simply declare the Repository as a Bean, which I did.

```
@Bean
public CustomRepository(NamedParameterJdbcOperations jdbcOperations) {
    return new CustomRepositoryImpl(jdbcOperations);
}
```

After that Spring was able to wire the Repository. I looked at the [github code](https://github.com/habuma/SpringInActionExamples/tree/master/Chapter_10/jdbc/src/main) of the book in hope for a better understanding, but unfortunately only the Bean solution, which runs, is implemented there.

So here are my questions:

1.) what possible reasons are there for a Bean definition, is a scenario  like this one, not to be recognized by the component scan?

2.) this project already uses Spring JPA Data Repositories, are there any reasons not to use both approaches at the same time?

Comment: Can you please check which packages are you informing in your @ComponentScan annotation and if the repository is on a child of it.

Comment: the @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"de.myproject.*"}) and the repository is in a sub-package de.myproject.performance, all other beans from different sub-packages are found, but maybe there are some special rules for @Repositorys I'm unaware of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is naming of your classes. There are many things to understand here.

1. You define a repository Interface @Repository is optional provided it extends CRUDRepository or one of the repositories provided by spring-data. In this class you can declare methods(find By....). And spring-data will formulate the query based on the underlying database. You can also specify your query using @Query.
2. Suppose you have a method which involves complex query or something which spring-data cannot do out of the box, in such case we can use the underlying template class for example JdbcTemplate or MongoTemplate..
3. The procedure to do this is to create another interface and a Impl class. The naming of this interface  should be exactly like Custom and your Impl class should be named Impl.. And all should be in same package.

For example if your Repository name is AbcRepository then Your custom repository should be named AbcRepositoryCustom and the implementation should be named AbcRepositoryImpl.. AbcRepository extends AbcRepositoryCustom(and also other spring-data Repositories). And AbcRepositoryImpl implements AbcRepositoryCustom

Answer (score 0):

I was able to "solve" the problem myself.

As we also have a front end class annotated with the same `basePackage` for the `@ComponentScan`

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"de.myproject.*"})
```

so there were actually two identical `@ComponentScan`s annotations which I wasn't aware off and this did lead to a conflict. It seams the ordering how the whole application had to be loaded had changed, but thats only me guessing.

I simply moved my `Repository` and its `Impl` to a subpackage, and changed the

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"de.myproject.subpackage.*"})
```

and now everything works fine. Though it escapes me, what the exact reason behind this behavior is.